# Single SQL command to get a value, then to update that value

Tags: java, mysql, sql

**Main question**

Is there a SQL command where I can select a value from a table row, and within that same SQL command update that value?

**Question in more detail**

I'm working on an e-commerce site where I use MYSQL Database which has a `products` table that has a list of, wait for it, products.

Included in this table is a `quantity` field and a `sold` field.

The `quantity` indicates the total amount of that product that was made, and the `sold` is the current amount of that product that is sold/users purchased.

So if the `sold` field ever matches the `quantity` I want to update the front end HTML to indicate that it is OUT OF STOCK.

So when a user purchases 'x' amount of a product, I know I can do the following two SQL commands to update the `sold` field:

`SELECT sold FROM products WHERE productID = ?`

I'd back fill that `?` with the id of the product that was just purchased.

After getting that `sold` value I'd add to that the amount the user just purchased, then do an UPDATE command such as:

`UPDATE products SET sold = ? WHERE productID = ?`

Is doing two different SQL Commands the best way to do this? or is it better to have this combined in a single SQL command?

Also, how could I best **lock** this specific `product` in the table using SQL statements, so that if a user A purchases product 'xyz' at the same time user B purchases the same product there isn't a race condition for the `sold` field that I want to update?

UPDATE:
I'm using java to communicate with the MYSQL database.

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: I'm using Java to talk with the MySQL database.

Comment: Are you using Spring, pure JDBC, something else?

Comment: Have you tried just increasing the value? UPDATE products SET sold = sold + ? WHERE productID = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do this as two separate SQL statements. In fact, it's necessary.

You do it like this:

```
START TRANSACTION; 

SELECT sold FROM products WHERE productID = ? FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE products SET sold = ? WHERE productID = ?;

COMMIT;
```

(Those are the SQL statements, but adapting it to Java or whatever other programming language is up to you. There may also be Java methods to use for the start transaction and commit, those do the same thing, so it's fine to use them.)

The `FOR UPDATE` acquires a lock on the rows examined, the same type of lock that would be acquired by an `UPDATE`. The lock is held until the transaction commits. So you can update it without concern about race conditions with concurrent sessions.

But make sure to do the SELECT, UPDATE, and COMMIT promptly. I see many developers do the SELECT... FOR UPDATE and then in between that and the UPDATE, their application does a bunch of other code, including things that might take a while, like calling the APIs of other services. You want to get to the COMMIT without delay, because the lock will make other concurrent sessions wait.

Comment: The OP is using Java, not raw MySQL.

Comment: That's fine, there are methods to start and commit the transaction. I'm just demonstrating the sequence of actions, not the literal code to invoke them. Anyone who is asking this question should be able to look up how to do it in their respective language and interface.

Comment: @Strawberry, I think I can guess where you're going with that comment. One could UPDATE without fetching the value first, for example to `SET sold = sold + 10`. But it's possible the app needs to display the old and new value to report the update. Or check the value against some configured bounds before updating. There are other possible reasons to fetch as well as UPDATE. The OP asked how to fetch the value and update it, and that's what I answered.

Comment: @Strawberry, You're welcome to post an answer of your own.

Comment: @all What Bill Karwin is what I needed.  I know how to do a SQL select and then act on the retrieved parameter and then subsequently update.  What I didn't know was if there is a better way, more specifically, a single command that could do that, **and** how to lock the `product` row in question to avoid race conditions. I marked his response as the answer as I've done what he recommended in Java and it works.